# Is there an Apple Watch app allowing me to display full-screen image?

Tags: iphone-app

I managed to display an image on Apple Watch by uploading content to the secondary Instagram account I follow: https://twitter.com/stefek99/status/631820801734516737

That's not good enough.

I would like to display full-screen image on the Apple Watch...

Maybe a glance app that doesn't display time but just an image?